# Jquery Mobile: Can I use stopPropagation in the pagebeforehide handler?

Tags: jquery-mobile, hide, stoppropagation

On one of my pages, I want to ask users first whether they want to navigate away. When user answers no, no transition should occur.

I tried this code:

```
$('#pTakeCardSet').live('pagebeforehide',function(event, ui){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

But it doesn't work. The new page is still loaded.

Does anyone have the same problem?

Answer (score 2):

You may be getting bit by a live event - from : http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

> Since the .live() method handles
>   events once they have propagated to
>   the top of the document, it is not
>   possible to stop propagation of live
>   events. Similarly, events handled by
>   .delegate() will always propagate to
>   the element to which they are
>   delegated; event handlers on any
>   elements below it will already have
>   been executed by the time the
>   delegated event handler is called.

Comment: i have tried to change it to "bind" and put the codes inside the "mobileinit" event handler and it still doesn't work